# Running a Procedure in an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, procedure

I have a procedure to create a new sheet based on available data. Basically, it creates a sheet based on the name of the data. The code is written as follows. It does work actually if I assign the procedure one by one.

```
Sub new_profile(tankname)
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = tankname
    ActiveSheet.Name = Range("b4").Value

end sub
```

Due to the fact that I will use this code for another workbook (which means there is no exact amount of data), I try to assign an array to automatically run the procedure all in one without call it one by one. The code is as follow:

```
Sub calculate_all()

Dim cel As Range
Dim tank_name() As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim n As Integer

i = 11
n = Range("B6").Value

ReDim tank_name(i)

For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(11, 2), Cells(11 + n, 2))
    tank_name(i) = cel.Value
    i = i + 1
    
    new_profile tank_name(i)
    ReDim Preserve tank_name(i)
    
Next cel
```

End Sub

Unfortunately, it becomes error and shows the message "subscript out of range". How could I solve this problem?

Comment: `ReDim Preserve` within a loop is an expensive task. You should size the array beforehand or just read the `.Value` of the `Range` in question into a 2D Variant array, in one step.

Comment: Please swap this two lines - increment i and call new_profile: first create new sheet and after that add 1 to i

Comment: why add the name to an array? it does nothing.  just do: `new_profile cel.value` inside the loop.

Comment: You load `tank_name(i) = cel.Value`, then you have `i = i + 1` and after that `new_profile tank_name(i)`. `tank_name(i)` does not exist. `i` is already bigger then the array dimension. The array has not yet being appropriately dimension-ed. And which is the purpose of using an array (even not wrongly)?

Comment: Bro @faneduru, you have just inspired me to change the order of  i+1 and new_profile tank_name(i)
i+1 should be put at last to make sure i has the appropriate value for tank_name(i). It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Each Element in Array Run a Procedure

- Let's say that creating a new profile means adding a new sheet, renaming it and writing the name to a cell.
- The 1st, main procedure `createProfiles` does the previously mentioned only if a worksheet with the current name in the `TankNames` array doesn't exist.
- The 2nd procedure `deleteProfiles` deletes all sheets if their names exist in the `TankNames` array.
- The 3rd and the 4th procedure are called by both previously mentioned procedures, while the 5th is obviously only called by the main procedure.
- Before running any of the first two procedures, adjust the constants in them to fit your needs.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub createProfiles()

    ' Source
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1" ' Tab Name
    Const FirstRow As Long = 11
    Const NameCol As Variant = "B" ' e.g. 1 or "A", 2 or "B"...
    ' Target
    Const CellAddress As String = "B4"
    ' Other
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    ' Write tank names from Source Worksheet to TankNames array.
    Dim TankNames As Variant
    getColumn TankNames, ws, NameCol, FirstRow

    Dim i As Long
    ' Loop through elements of TankNames array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(TankNames)
        ' For each tank name create a new profile.
        If Not foundSheetName(wb, TankNames(i, 1)) Then
            Call createProfile wb, TankNames(i, 1), CellAddress
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub deleteProfiles()
    ' Source
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1" ' Tab Name
    Const FirstRow As Long = 11
    Const NameCol As Variant = "B" ' e.g. 1 or "A", 2 or "B"...
    ' Other
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    ' Write tank names from Source Worksheet to TankNames array.
    Dim TankNames As Variant
    getColumn TankNames, ws, NameCol, FirstRow

    Dim i As Long
    ' Loop through elements of TankNames array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(TankNames)
        ' For each tank name delete profile (sheet).
        If foundSheetName(wb, TankNames(i, 1)) Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb.Worksheets(TankNames(i, 1)).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub getColumn(ByRef Data As Variant, _
              Sheet As Worksheet, _
              Optional ByVal ColumnID As Variant = 1, _
              Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1)
    
    Data = Empty
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(ColumnID).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
    Set rng = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(FirstRow, ColumnID), rng)
    
    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Data = rng.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
    
End Sub
    
Function foundSheetName(Book As Workbook, _
                        Optional ByVal SheetName As String = "Sheet1") _
         As Boolean
    If Book Is Nothing Then Set Book = ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Book.Worksheets(SheetName)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then foundSheetName = True
End Function

Sub createProfile(Book As Workbook, _
                  ByVal NewName As String, _
                  ByVal NameCellAddress As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Book.Worksheets.Add(After:=Book.Sheets(Book.Sheets.Count))
    With ws
        .Name = NewName
        .Range(NameCellAddress) = NewName
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's great sir! Prior to your help, I could only delete available sheet using some codes that will delete all sheet but the program stop running and I found them very disturbing. The logic you proposed does help to complete my program.